# Update table if no data from other table matches

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Definition of both tables (it's just an example, I can't merge tables, no):

```
CREATE TABLE `MyTable`(
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `a` varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
  `b`  varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `state` tinyint NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Goal: Update MyTable1 records that don't share any value with "a" OR "b" from MyTable2.

My solution:

```
update MyTable1 as t1 
  inner join MyTable2 as t2 on (t1.a != t2.a and t1.b != t2.b) 
set t1.state=3;
```

I'm basically joining tables where no columns match, so that I can update the state of such records.

My problem: This is slow. It took 6 seconds with 5000 entries in MyTable1 and 3000 entries in MyTable2.

Question: Can it be any faster (if your solution goes a lot faster, I'll take it too ;)?

EDIT: My "solution" actually doesn't work at all.

Comment: Have defined indexes on the columns a,b?

Comment: Yes, BTREE per column, on both tables

Comment: The update statement seems correct. You need to put an index on the fields `a` and `b` on both tables. In general if you do a join always put an index on the fields listed in the join's `ON` section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your join might find a ton of matches per row.  That can make a join really expensive.  Try a `not exists` instead:

```
update  MyTable1 as t1
set     t1.state = 3
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    MyTable2 as t2 
        where   t1.a = t2.a 
                or t1.b = t2.b
        )
```

or even a double subquery:

```
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    MyTable2 as t2 
        where   t1.a = t2.a 
        )
        and not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    MyTable2 as t2 
        where   t1.b = t2.b
        )
```

Comment: Isn't `not exists` slow in MySQL?

Comment: @Andomar: Yours took 3seconds only but only updated 500 records in my test. Let me figure out which one is wrong (mine or yours), I'll get back to you.

Comment: @Andomar: I just realized that mine actually doesn't work. I haven't done much SQL over the last 2 years so I'm still looking why all rows match. Yours works. Now lets see what Johan has to offer.

Comment: My solution was the following: "update mytable1 i left join mytable2 n on i.a = n.a or i.b = n.b set i.state=3 where n.a is null;", which is 10% slower than your first solution. I tried your second solution and it actually looks like it works 500 times faster. I'll check a few more things tomorrow to validate. If it works, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

This might be faster:

```
UPDATE table1 t1 SET t1.state = 3
WHERE t1.id IN
  (SELECT s.id FROM 
     (SELECT T2.id FROM Table1 t2
      LEFT JOIN table2 t3 ON (t2.a = t3.a AND t2.b = t3.b)
      WHERE T3.ID IS NULL
     ) s
  )
```

Comment: [Err] 1093 - You can't specify target table 't1' for update in FROM clause

Comment: @iDemmel, rewrote and tested the query in MySQLbrowser, this works. But.... is it faster?

Comment: It executes but 1000 rows are changed in my example, only 500 should get changed. It takes 320ms in my example (1 row updated every 7 rows). 72ms for the example of Andomar.